# tensorflow : why multi rnn-rstm result is not consistent?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

i'm studying rnn.

I want to make multi rnn-rstm model(many input one output) like this

50~60(input 3 data) -> 0(answer)

60~70 -> 1

70~80 -> 2

(example)

```
51, 52, 57 -> 0  
67, 64, 68 -> 1  
73, 77, 78 -> 2  
53, 55, 51 -> 0   
62, 66, 63 -> 1   
73, 70, 73 -> 2
```

but result is not converge like below.

early result is good.

number....  input_data ........answer...........hypothesis...........cost(loss)

```
9995   [[64, 65, 60]]   [[1]]   [[ 1.0044558]]   1.98542e-05
9996   [[70, 71, 77]]   [[2]]   [[ 1.99514413]]   2.35795e-05
9997   [[52, 52, 58]]   [[0]]   [[ 0.00810847]]   6.57474e-05
9998   [[61, 65, 61]]   [[1]]   [[ 1.00867283]]   7.5218e-05
9999   [[79, 72, 71]]   [[2]]   [[ 2.0111196]]   0.000123646
10000   [[56, 55, 58]]   [[0]]   [[-0.00018287]]   3.34404e-08
```

but after some learning, result is not converge

number....  input_data ........answer...........hypothesis...........cost(loss)

```
29995   [[51, 52, 57]]   [[0]]   [[ 1.00436962]]   1.00876
29996   [[67, 64, 68]]   [[1]]   [[ 0.99985003]]   2.24896e-08
29997   [[73, 77, 78]]   [[2]]   [[ 0.9957822]]   1.00845
29998   [[53, 55, 51]]   [[0]]   [[ 1.00436962]]   1.00876
29999   [[62, 66, 63]]   [[1]]   [[ 0.99985003]]   2.24896e-08
30000   [[73, 70, 73]]   [[2]]   [[ 0.9957822]]   1.00845
```

if anyone knows reason, please let me know.

environment = anaconda

full source code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn
import csv
import argparse
import os



csv_file = "./data3.csv"

batch_size = 1
input_sequence_length = 3 
output_sequence_length = 1
input_num_classes = 80
output_num_classes = 3
learning_rate = 0.1
rnn_stack = 5
hidden_size = 4

with tf.name_scope("placeholder") as scope:

    X = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, input_sequence_length], name="x_input")
    X_one_hot = tf.one_hot(X, input_num_classes)

    Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, output_sequence_length], name="y_input")  # 1
    Y_one_hot = tf.one_hot(Y, output_num_classes)  # one hot
    Y_one_hot = tf.reshape(Y_one_hot, [-1, output_num_classes])

    X_one_hot = tf.reshape(X_one_hot, [batch_size, input_sequence_length, input_num_classes])
    outputs = tf.to_float(X_one_hot)


with tf.name_scope("rnn") as scope:

    # Make a lstm cell with hidden_size (each unit output vector size)
    def lstm_cell():
        cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size, state_is_tuple=True)
        return cell

    multi_cells = rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell() for _ in range(rnn_stack)], state_is_tuple=True)

    # outputs: unfolding size x hidden size, state = hidden size
    outputs, _states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multi_cells, X_one_hot, dtype=tf.float32)

    Y_pred = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(outputs[:, -1], 1, activation_fn=None)


with tf.name_scope("cost") as scope:

    cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(Y_pred - tf.to_float(Y)))

with tf.name_scope("train") as scope:

    train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

with tf.name_scope("get_input_data") as scope:

    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([csv_file])
    key, value = tf.TextLineReader().read(filename_queue)

    input_list = []
    for l in range(input_sequence_length + output_sequence_length):
        input_list.append([1])

    data = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=input_list)


with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    step=0
    while step < 30000:
        step+=1
        datas = sess.run(data)

        dataX = []
        dataY = []
        # if testing max value = dataX.append(datas[0:-2]) dataY.append(datas[-2:-1])
        # else if testing min value = dataX.append(datas[0:-2]) dataY.append(datas[-1:])
        dataX.append(datas[0:-1])
        dataY.append(datas[-1:])

        _, hypo, loss= sess.run([train, Y_pred, cost], feed_dict={X: dataX, Y: dataY})

        print(step, " ", dataX, " ", dataY, " ", hypo, " ", loss)

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: when rnn_stack is 1~3 result is ok. But rnn_stack is deeper than 5 result is bad.

Comment: when rnn_stack is deeper than 5, hypothsis is [0.33 0.33 0.33]